# Knockout JS Multiple click binding

Tags: jquery, data-binding, knockout.js

When I click an anchor I want it to save the object (which works fine), and I also want to make the button invisible.  I need to make the 'InQuestionBank()' property true when I click on the button.  If I change the data-bind on the anchor to:

```
<a data-bind="click: InQuestionBank, visible: !InQuestionBank()" href="#" class="saveBank btn btn-info title" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Insert into question bank"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i></a>
```

The button will disappear.  Is it possible to have multiple click bindings, or is there a better way to do it?

Here is what I currently have for my anchor in my view:

```
<a data-bind="click: $parent.SaveQuestionBank, visible: !InQuestionBank()" href="#" class="saveBank btn btn-info title" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Insert into question bank"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i></a>
```

My Knockout code:

```
var Question = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Type = ko.observable(data.Type);
    self.Question = ko.observable(data.Question);
    self.Options = ko.observable(data.Options);
    self.InQuestionBank = ko.observable(data.InQuestionBank);
}

var ViewModel = function (initial) {
    var self = this;
    self.Questions = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.SaveQuestionBank = function (question) {
        $.ajax({
            url: initial.SaveQuestionBankUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: ko.toJSON({ question: question }),
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.status == "OK") {
                    $.msgGrowl({
                        type: 'success',
                        title: 'Question Bank',
                        text: 'Successfully saved question in question bank.'
                    });
                }
                else if (data.status == "ERROR") {
                    $.msgGrowl({
                        type: 'error',
                        title: 'Question Bank',
                        text: 'An error occurred - please try again.'
                    });
                }

                self.OverallQuestionsBank.push(new OverallQuestionBank({
                    Question: question.Question(),
                    Type: question.Type(),
                    Options: question.Options()
                }));
            }
        });
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < initial.questions.length; i++) {
        self.Questions.push(new Question(initial.questions[i], initial.ParentID));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just change the flag 'InQuestionBank' while you are pushing it to the server or into OverallQuestionsBank?

Comment: Inside the SaveQuestionBank function I tried 'self.InQuestionBank = true;' but that didn't work.

Comment: Check my answer it will work for you and I will explain why in a second

Comment: Sounds good, remember that in Knockout to get a value we need to use the 'getter' function and setting a value requires the use of the 'setter' function.  The only time you don't need to do that is if you already have the value (In your example since you have passed in the 'question's value already you don't need question().InQuestionBank(true) simply question.InQuestionBank(true))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change the questions flag 'InQuestionBank' like shown below

```
var Question = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Type = ko.observable(data.Type);
    self.Question = ko.observable(data.Question);
    self.Options = ko.observable(data.Options);
    self.InQuestionBank = ko.observable(data.InQuestionBank);
}

var ViewModel = function (initial) {
    var self = this;
    self.Questions = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.SaveQuestionBank = function (question) {

        // Change the question's flag
        question.InQuestionBank(true);

        $.ajax({
            url: initial.SaveQuestionBankUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: ko.toJSON({ question: question }),
            success: function (data) {
                self.OverallQuestionsBank.push(new OverallQuestionBank({
                    Question: question.Question(),
                    Type: question.Type(),
                    Options: question.Options()
                }));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Remember that when you are changing the value of an observable property (such as InQuestionBank) you need to use Knockout's 'setter' function to set the new value.

In this case it would be question.InQuestionBank(true)

Comment: I forgot about the 'setter' function for setting the new value.  I was completely overthinking it.